# Navigate to special line of file in Visual Studio + ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Are there any way in VS + ReSharper for navigate to special line number?

Comment: What is a "special line number"?

Comment: Do you mean a "particular" line number, or a "specific" line number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you mean, but if you simply want to navigate to a specific line in a file, use <kbd>Ctrl + g</kbd> and enter the line number.

This is the same as the `Edit -> Go To...` menu item.

Answer (score 9):

With ReSharper 8 onwards, you can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, type in something like `Foo.cs 20` and go to line 20 in the file Foo.cs.